# I can't clone repository with AWS CodeCommit. What does it mean?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Although all permissions are already set, when I try to make the "git clone" from a repository in CodeCommit I get the following message:

> fatal: unable to access 'NAME_OF_REPOSITORY': gnutls_handshake() failed: Illegal parameter

This only happens with AWS CodeCommit, but no with any type of another git repository.